# It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have installed multiple versions of .NET Sdk.Now the Omnisharp suggestions is not working fine.

output shows these

```
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /BO-V2/Techne-Travel/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/src/Application/Application.csproj
A compatible installed .NET SDK for global.json version [6.0.101] from [/BO-V2/Techne-Travel/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/global.json] was not found.
Install the [6.0.101] .NET SDK or update [/BO-V2/Techne-Travel/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/global.json] with an installed .NET SDK:
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
Install a .NET SDK from:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
A compatible installed .NET SDK for global.json version [6.0.101] from [/BO-V2/Techne-Travel/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/global.json] was not found.
Install the [6.0.101] .NET SDK or update [/BO-V2/Techne-Travel/travel-techne-bo-for-ota/global.json] with an installed .NET SDK:
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
Install a .NET SDK from:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        Unable to locate the .NET SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
```

But dotnet --info shows this output

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.101
 Commit:    ef49f6213a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.1
  Commit:  3a25a7f1cc

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.415 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.209 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.403 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.21 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.12 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.21 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.13 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

which dotnet command

```
/usr/bin/dotnet
```

I have searched in google and find this
https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1941159.

I did below as they said.
But Still I face the same issue.
Why this issue? How can I solve this
setting.json

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": false
    },
    "omnisharp.path": "latest",
}
```

omnisharp.json

```
{
    "MsBuild": {
        "UseLegacySdkResolver": true
    }
}
```

global.json

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.101",
    "rollForward": "latestMinor"
  }
}
```

What should I do to make omnisharp works fine?
I could not continue the work without Omnisharp Suggestion. It is hard to code. Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the documentation here https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode

> Using .NET 6 builds of OmniSharp Starting with C# extension version
> 1.24.0, there is now an option to use build of OmniSharp that runs on the .NET 6 SDK. This build requires that the .NET 6 SDK be installed
> and does not use Visual Studio MSBuild tools or Mono. It only supports
> newer SDK-style projects that are buildable with dotnet build. Unity
> projects and other Full Framework projects are not supported.
>
> To use the .NET 6 build, set `omnisharp.useModernNet` to `true` in your VS
> Code settings and restart OmniSharp.